# Shared memory between multiple child process

Tags: c, fork, shared

Is it even possible? Using `thread` is forbidden for the program I'm trying to make.

The program `fork` N times to read from N`pipes` and prints its content. I need to have a global variable shared between the child process that can affect all the child when it is changed (Simply to put `\n` at the right place).

So far I've tried to replicate example with parents and child using shmget and shmat without success. I often get `segmentation fault`.

Is there somewhere a simple example on how to shared a variable between forked child?

An example of an output I'm looking for:

```
Program 1 = 
Hello
Program 2 = 
Hi
Program 1 =
World 
Program 1 = 
End
Program 2=
World2
Program 2=
End2
```

Sometimes the output has been printed with a `newline` character, sometimes not and I need to insert from time to time `newline` character.

Comment: This is most likely an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: The program I'm writing execute other program and print their output. I need to differentiate which output comes from which program, thus I can't use a single pipe for all process. If you think the real problem is this part, I would be curious to know how you would approach it differently.

Comment: Differentiate how? You can differentiate by the process ID (each process knows its own). Or you can pass a unique identifier to each spawned process. Post an example output.

Comment: I added an example, I think your idea of differentiating with PID might be a good idea.

Comment: Or you can have a variable, which you will increment before each `fork`, so each forked process will have a different number in it.

Comment: I'm already doing this and I don't have a problem with the indexing the program part, it's the newline character that cause me problem. Sometimes a program has an echo with a newline character, sometimes not, and I need to have a global variable that dictate the different child whether or not to skip a line. Don't know if that was clear enough.

Comment: Not really. Are you saying that the output from one child should depend on another child?

Comment: Exactly, some program are passed as argument to my program. Those are shell script that ```echo``` a couple of line each. Sometime the ```echo``` has the ```-n``` option, which cause the output to not skipline after being echoed. Thus the output from one child should affect the output of another whether there was a newline character at the end of the string echoed or not. If there wasn't a new line character, the next output should print a newline character before it's normal print.

Comment: https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2012/spring/cs641/lecture/04_05_fork_mmap.html